# Call Host method from IPlugin

Tags: c#, plugins

I'm currently building a plugin system using IPluginInterface. The plugins include the whole logic, the host just enables/disables the plugins and configures them.

However, there are certain Host methods I should be able to call from a plugin. I've tested various ideas, but none of them seems to work fine.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the host implementing `IHost` ( somethin like this ), have the plugin exposing a function ( ie `Initizialize(IHost host)` ) and pass the host to the plugin.

Comment: sorry for asking, but when you say IHost, do you mean an own implementation or IHost in a certain namespace? The only IHost I can find is in the Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM namespace (?!)

Comment: @Michael Hofer, yeah I mean your custom IHost, call it as you like, is just a way to pass a contract to your Host program.